# What is the difference between connection.commit() and cursor.execute('commit')?

Tags: python, oracle

I want to know that performance wise which is a better option i.e. after inserting rows should we use `connection.commit()` or `cursor.execute('commit')` considering the fact that I am using Oracle database.

Comment: I don't know for sure, as I didn't write the `cx_Oracle` module, but I strongly suspect that there is next-to-no difference in performance between the two.  Is there a reason you're asking which one of them performs better?

Comment: The latter invokes the SQL engine in the DB.  But both require a 'round-trip' to the database, which can be avoided with `connection.autocommit`.  However you don't want to autocommit everything - that's bad for transactional consistency and performance.  Just commit once at the end of each transaction, preferably with autocommit if your application architecture allows it.

Comment: Reason I am asking is that I am doing some database testing for insert performance and trying to simulate load coming from application. So it is really important to know what is the difference in terms of performance between the two.

Comment: The most performant is [`connection.autocommit`](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/connection.html#Connection.autocommit) because it is 'piggy backed' with the `execute()` or `executemany()` and doesn't require a ['round-trip'](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tuning.html#roundtrips) that the other two take.

Comment: I was reminded today that if you want to take advantage of Oracle Application Continuity in current versions of Oracle, you should not use `cursor.execute('commit')`.  (There's an enhancement request 29928268 logged in Oracle's bug system to support this use with AC.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the documentation, the only apparent difference is that both belong to different objects

> **Connection.commit()**
> Commit any pending transactions to the database.

> **Cursor.execute()** Execute a statement against the database

1. If you have more than one cursor against the same connection, `connection.commit()` will commit any pending transaction which can belong to any cursor in the program.
2. `cursor.execute('commit')` you would think that only pending transaction that belongs to the corresponding cursor will be committed. Here is the misconception, because once you commit any of the cursor in the corresponding connection, all of the remaining will be committed as well.

A demo of what I just explained:

**Demo table**

```
SQL> desc test_cursors
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 D                                                  DATE
 ID                                                 VARCHAR2(100)
```

**Simple python program**

```
import cx_Oracle

host="ODCGRC1R.SCGER.DEV.CORP"
port=60995
sid='odcgrc1r'
user='CPL_REP'
password='Cpl3_r3p'
sid = cx_Oracle.makedsn(host, port, service_name=sid)

sql = ('insert into test_cursors values(sysdate,1)')

connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user, password, sid, encoding="UTF-8")
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql)
connection.commit()
```

We execute it to just insert one record, no matter what method we use the result is the same.

```
C:\python>python testconn.py

C:\python>sqlplus cpl_rep/Cpl3_r3p@//ODCGRC1R.SCGER.DEV.CORP:60995/odcgrc1r

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Sun Oct 3 11:54:18 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Sun Oct 03 2021 11:54:14 +02:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production

SQL> select * from test_cursors ;

D
---------
ID
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
03-OCT-21
1
```

So far, so good. Our record has been committed into the table by the connection method commit ( it would have been the same by `cursor.execute('commit')`. Now, let's use it with several statements with the same cursor

```
import cx_Oracle

host="ODCGRC1R.SCGER.DEV.CORP"
port=60995
sid='odcgrc1r'
user='CPL_REP'
password='Cpl3_r3p'
sid = cx_Oracle.makedsn(host, port, service_name=sid)

sql1 = ('insert into test_cursors values(sysdate,2)')
sql2 = ('insert into test_cursors values(sysdate,3)')

connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user, password, sid, encoding="UTF-8")
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql1)
cursor.execute(sql2)
connection.commit()
```

Let's run it and confirm that all records have been inserted.

```
C:\python>python testconn.py

C:\python>sqlplus cpl_rep/Cpl3_r3p@//ODCGRC1R.SCGER.DEV.CORP:60995/odcgrc1r

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Sun Oct 3 11:56:49 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Sun Oct 03 2021 11:56:44 +02:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production

SQL>  select * from test_cursors ;

D                  ID
-------------------------------------------------------------------
03-OCT-21          1

03-OCT-21          2

03-OCT-21          3
```

Well, as predicted, the `connection.commit()` method has done its job, committing all pending transactions in the connection.

Now, let's switch to `cursor.execute('commit')` instead. In the next example, on purpose, I am creating two different cursors from the same connection, but I am only going to commit one of them. I am setting `autocommit` to false

```
import cx_Oracle

host="ODCGRC1R.SCGER.DEV.CORP"
port=60995
sid='odcgrc1r'
user='CPL_REP'
password='Cpl3_r3p'
sid = cx_Oracle.makedsn(host, port, service_name=sid)

sql1 = ('insert into test_cursors values(sysdate,4)')
sql2 = ('insert into test_cursors values(sysdate,5)')

connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user, password, sid, encoding="UTF-8")
connection.autocommit = False
cursor1 = connection.cursor()
cursor2 = connection.cursor()
cursor1.execute(sql1)
cursor2.execute(sql2)
cursor1.execute('commit')
```

We execute it

```
C:\python>python testconn.py

C:\python>sqlplus cpl_rep/Cpl3_r3p@//ODCGRC1R.SCGER.DEV.CORP:60995/odcgrc1r

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Sun Oct 3 12:06:13 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Sun Oct 03 2021 12:06:11 +02:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production

SQL> set lines 80
SQL> col id for a20
SQL> select * from test_cursors ;

D         ID
--------- --------------------
03-OCT-21 1
03-OCT-21 2
03-OCT-21 3
03-OCT-21 4
03-OCT-21 5
```

Well, even though the cursor 2 was not committed in the program, it did indeed commit in the database. Why ? Because both of them belong to the same `connection.cursor()` , therefore when I commit one, I was indeed committing all of them.

Coming back to the purpose of your question, I believe both of them are the same in terms of what is happening in the database. Normally speaking I would use `connection.commit()` for closing a connection with any number of different transactions. However, for performance reasons, if you are handling big transactions, it is better to commit some work along the way, for example to avoid undo problems. But again, that depends entirely of what your code is doing.

Comment: Thanks Roberto for such a detailed explanation. Just one more question what about another variant of this example say I have a for loop inserting records into a single table and I want to commit after say 100 records still connection.commit and cursor.execute will work in same way ?

Comment: You would turn on autocommit for the last insert, and turn it off for all the others.  For data loads, review the use of `executemany()`, see the cx_Oracle doc [Batch Statement Execution and Bulk Loading](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html).  But for huge data loads the round-trip of an explicit commit may not make any difference.  I would say that you really may not want to be committing until all data is loaded. There are plenty of other discussions about this if you search.

Comment: @Atif, regarding your comment, yes they will work in the same way. 100 records is nothing.